# How to interface digital output of FPGA to a DAC?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, digital-analog-converter

I currently have a very, very basic DDS core(?) with a counter, tuning word, and sine LUT that outputs 16 bit values to correlate with a sin value for a DAC. I am using the [Nexys 4 DDR board](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/nexys-4-ddr/start?redirect=1id=nexys4-ddr:start) and my [DAC](http://store.digilentinc.com/pmodda3-one-16-bit-d-a-output/) is a peripheral module designed exclusively for FPGAs. **If its a 16-bit DAC, why does it have 6 pins, only 4 of which are for data? And how should I send the binary information from my 16-bit generated sin value to the DAC in order for the DAC to do a successful conversion?**

Here is my code (I know its rudimentary, please forgive the mistakes, I will work them out once I properly know how to interact with the DAC!)

```
module sin_LUT(
  input clk,
  input [0:3] M,
  input rst,
  output reg [16:0] data_out,
  output reg [32:0]test
);

//counter

//declaring constant
integer i;
integer int_M;

always @(M)
  int_M = M;

always @(posedge(clk))
begin
if (rst)
  i <= 0;
else if (i >= 29)
  i <= 0;
else
  i <= i + M;
end

//testing purposes
always @(i)
  test = i;

//sine LUT
always @(i) begin
  case (i)
    0: data_out = 16'D32768;
    1: data_out = 16'D39812;
    2: data_out = 16'D46526;
    3: data_out = 16'D52598;
    4: data_out = 16'D57742;
    5: data_out = 16'D61718;
    6: data_out = 16'D64341;
    7: data_out = 16'D65487;
    8: data_out = 16'D65103;
    9: data_out = 16'D63208;
    10: data_out = 16'D59889;
    11: data_out = 16'D55302;
    12: data_out = 16'D49661;
    13: data_out = 16'D43230;
    14: data_out = 16'D36310;
    15: data_out = 16'D29225;
    16: data_out = 16'D22305;
    17: data_out = 16'D15874;
    18: data_out = 16'D10233;
    19: data_out = 16'D5646;
    20: data_out = 16'D2327;
    21: data_out = 16'D432;
    22: data_out = 16'D48;
    23: data_out = 16'D1194;
    24: data_out = 16'D3817;
    25: data_out = 16'D7793;
    26: data_out = 16'D12937;
    27: data_out = 16'D19009;
    28: data_out = 16'D25723;
    29: data_out = 16'D32768;
    default: data_out = 16'b0000111100001111;
  endcase
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datasheet for this DAC board says it uses an Analog Devices AD5541 DAC:

http://www.analog.com/en/products/digital-to-analog-converters/da-converters/ad5541a.html

The product page also has a link to the DAC datasheet. From this datasheet I pulled the following information: This thing uses a SPI interface. A *select* line (CS) which you pull low to indicate the DAC that you want to send it data. A *data* line (DIN) at which each single bit is presented. And a *clock* line (SCLK) that makes the DAC read a bit from the data line the moment it goes from low to high.

Here's the timing diagram[image: AD5541 SPI timing]

The LDAC input, if pulled low, tells the DAC to output with every update of the serial data register.

---

When developing electronics being able to source documentation and reading it is paramount. I've used a couple of different SPI DACs in various projects already, also some from AD. But not the AD5541 one. But the whole answer above I used information I got from reading the relevant datasheets for a couple of minutes. If programming FPGAs is your thing that you absolutely must cultivate the skill to do as such.